# Add file to unsaved model entity in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to save a file in a dependent model entity when the parent (base) entity has not yet been saved?

I would like the user to be able to add images to a story prior to the story actually being saved. So my model is like this:

```
Story (Base Entity) has_many :pictures
  + Picture (Depedent Entity) belongs_to :story
```

In the Story controller, I have a separate action called add_image. However, because the instance variable @story does not seem to be persisted across requests, I cannot access it in this action.

What I have thought of doing so far is to store the @story variable in the session on create, so I can retrieve it from there. Will this work? May it have any unintended side-effects for subsequent requests? (E.g. what if I have the previous story stored in the session and add a picture to the wrong story?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is possible to save dependent records together with the main on first create:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

See the section "Unsaved objects and associations". You must use collection.build to add the dependent records.

Now my problem is still how to reliably persist the parent across requests, though I am thinking this may be possible by storing it in the session with the ID generated by mongoid (the only problem being that it is not portable across ORMs, I think).

*This answers part of my question. So I will not accept any answer just yet, and once I have found a proper solution, I will give an update.*

Comment: The problem I see is that if you have two browser windows open connected to the same session, you may update the wrong one with the additions (hence the idea of storing the parent by its ID, possibly only where the ID is generated up front, as in Mongoid, or some other ORM not using a relational DB). I wouldn't want the user to end up with tons of objects in the session though, but if the impact is minimal, maybe I will go with that idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just think about the implementation. There are two tables in the database and there should be some row `story_id` in the "pictures" table. What should be there, if story is not saved and it has no id yet?

Do it another way. Add some boolean flag to Stories, for example `finished`. Save all "unfinished" stories and change flag to "finished" on save in your application. Don't forget to regularly delete old "unfinished" (abandoned) stories and their pictures.

Comment: Thanks @Petr. I am using MongoDB + mongoid. When I create an instance of a Story, it fortunately has an ID already. So from that aspect it is not a problem. I don't want to fill the DB with unfinished stories, so if there is no such possibility, I will rather tell the user to save first. I can, in the console though, create a story, without saving, and add pictures, so I am guessing it must be possible. I will try with the session option as well, but I am just a little worried about the unintended consequences there.

Comment: Apparently it is possible: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html see "Unsaved objects and associations". You must use collection.build. Now my problem is still how to reliably persist the parent across requests, though I am thinking this may be possible by storing it in the session with the ID generated by mongoid (the only problem being that it is not portable across DBs, I think).